# Why can not input value be written outside of the function while h3 tag has no problem?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```js
var aranan = document.getElementById("myInput")

var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3")
var filter = aranan.value

function myFunction() {
  console.log(filter)
  console.log(h3[0])
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="word">our store</h1>
    <label for="">
            Search
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ara..." onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput">
          </label>

    <div class="menu" id="burasıda-id" data-name="yerel" data-surname="12.05.2020">
      <h2>all</h2>
      <h2>cakes</h2>
      <h2>cupcakes</h2>
      <h2>sweets</h2>
      <h2>dougnuts</h2>
    </div>
    <section>
      <h3 class="first">cake</h3>
      <h3 class="second">cupcake</h3>
      <h3 class="third">sweet</h3>
      <h3 class="fourth">dougnut</h3>
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Why does `console.log(h3[0])` work but `console.log(filter)` does not?

When I put the `var filter` into the function it works too.

But what can be the reason? Is it about input value should be in the function?

Comment: You fest value outside of key up event, then it has nothing in value, move var filter = aranan.value inside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this code executes *immediately* when the page loads:

```
var aranan = document.getElementById("myInput")

var h3 = document.getElementsByTagName("h3") 
var filter = aranan.value
```

And when the page first loads, the element has no value:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ara..." onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput">
```

So `filter` will be empty.  And since nothing ever changes that variable, it will always be empty.

In order to capture the value after the user has entered it, you need to read the `.value` property after it's been entered.  Inside `myFunction` seems like a good place to do that:

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log(aranan.value)
  console.log(h3[0])
}
```

The key difference here is that `aranan` and `h3` are holding references to *page elements* which do exist at the time those variables are set.  But `filter` is holding a literal value, and at the time you set that variable no value is in that input.

Comment: Thank you, i just want to be sure.